# using device camera for capturing image in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, camera, progressive-web-apps, webcam

can I access the device camera and take a photo in ReactJs? The goal is to create a component that allows the camera to take pictures with the click of a button. According to my studies, I should use mediaDevices, but I am looking for a sample code in ReactJs. Please provide me with a sample code, or if you have experience implementing this, please guide me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have prepared a sample code that can be used as a component. This code snippet is applicable to devices that also have two cameras. If you want to take a video instead of a photo, you can also enable the audio feature in the outputs.

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.cameraNumber = 0;

    this.state = {
      imageDataURL: null,
    };
  }

  initializeMedia = async () => {
    this.setState({ imageDataURL: null });

    if (!("mediaDevices" in navigator)) {
      navigator.mediaDevices = {};
    }

    if (!("getUserMedia" in navigator.mediaDevices)) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function (constraints) {
        var getUserMedia =
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        if (!getUserMedia) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error("getUserMedia Not Implemented"));
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
        });
      };
    }

    //Get the details of video inputs of the device
    const videoInputs = await this.getListOfVideoInputs();

    //The device has a camera
    if (videoInputs.length) {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: {
            deviceId: {
              exact: videoInputs[this.cameraNumber].deviceId,
            },
          },
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          this.player.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    } else {
      alert("The device does not have a camera");
    }
  };

  capturePicture = () => {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.player.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = this.player.videoHeight;
    var contex = canvas.getContext("2d");
    contex.drawImage(this.player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.player.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => {
      track.stop();
    });

    console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
    this.setState({ imageDataURL: canvas.toDataURL() });
  };

  switchCamera = async () => {
    const listOfVideoInputs = await this.getListOfVideoInputs();

    // The device has more than one camera
    if (listOfVideoInputs.length > 1) {
      if (this.player.srcObject) {
        this.player.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => {
          track.stop();
        });
      }

      // switch to second camera
      if (this.cameraNumber === 0) {
        this.cameraNumber = 1;
      }
      // switch to first camera
      else if (this.cameraNumber === 1) {
        this.cameraNumber = 0;
      }

      // Restart based on camera input
      this.initializeMedia();
    } else if (listOfVideoInputs.length === 1) {
      alert("The device has only one camera");
    } else {
      alert("The device does not have a camera");
    }
  };

  getListOfVideoInputs = async () => {
    // Get the details of audio and video output of the device
    const enumerateDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

    //Filter video outputs (for devices with multiple cameras)
    return enumerateDevices.filter((device) => device.kind === "videoinput");
  };

  render() {
    const playerORImage = Boolean(this.state.imageDataURL) ? (
      <img src={this.state.imageDataURL} alt="cameraPic" />
    ) : (
      <video
        ref={(refrence) => {
          this.player = refrence;
        }}
        autoPlay
      ></video>
    );

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {playerORImage}
        <button onClick={this.initializeMedia}>Take Photo</button>
        <button onClick={this.capturePicture}>Capture</button>
        <button onClick={this.switchCamera}>Switch</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have been searching how can I take a photo in a React application without using 3rd packages for nearly 3 hours. I came across your answer and I really appreciate it. People mostly intend to use 3rd party packages nearly for everything, it is so hard to find out an answer that how to make anything by using only the language itself. Thanks again.